# unable to display image in client machine

Tags: html

I have a web application.
I have inserted an image into my web application homepage using html tags.It is working very well in server machine. But when any client is accessing my web page everything that is present in the homepage of the web application is displayed except the image. Instead of image cross mark is displayed in client machine.

Can anybody help me how to display the image in client machine.

Comment: Can you post the offending code?

Answer (score 1):

Check the path in the src attribute in the img tag.  Make sure it's a relative path, and not hard coded to path on your hard drive.