# unable to display image in client machine

Tags: html

This is a duplicate of [unable to display image in client machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416985/unable-to-display-image-in-client-machine), by the same person.

I have a web application.
I have inserted an image into my web application homepage using html tags. It is working very well in server machine. But when any client is accessing my web page everything that is present in the homepage of the web application is displayed except the image. Instead of image cross mark is displayed in client machine.

Can anybody help me how to display the image in client machine.

Answer (score 0):

I should imagine you're not pointing to the right place on the server for the image. For example the image was hard coded to point to localhost. Perhaps also check the mappings in IIS.
If you could provide the source you are using that would possibly help.